# How to use 'order_by' with including non-ASCII characters in django?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am using python3 and sqlite on my database. I am trying to order words on specific languages. For example, I wrote this code part on my settings.py:

```
export LANG='tr_TR.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='tr_TR.UTF-8'
```

However, this code part gives syntax error. Eventhough I have fixed that syntax error, I assume that the problem will still continue.

Then I have tried to change this code part on settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-TR'
```

But it didn't work either.

I guess I have to change something on manage.py, but I don't know what should I change or add.

I hope that someone will help on my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `export` is not valid Python. This is typically used to export settings.

Comment: Yes, I realise that but  they wrote on this link.https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi

Comment: It's not django or python that orders your queries but the database. This database feature is callled Collation. There are no django settings to set. Instead for a sqlite database you will need to use ICU Collation Sequences Extension set to e.g. turkish.

Comment: @trixn So should I use ICU after migration or before migration ?